# C++ software design options, class relationships

Tags: c++, class, relationships

Problem:

I have totally separate software managers (software entities), for example CCarManager, CTruckManager etc.. At some point I am creating new objects for example CCar. CCar must have relationships with various separate managers, for example, with CResourceManager, CTruckManager. What is the best way to link CCar with these managers?

Solutions:

1. Have global software managers (Singleton or extern in header file)
   [Don't like globals]
2. Use one global point and pass it to other obects e.g CCar(CApplication), CApplication->TrukManager(), CApplication->CarManager()... 
   [Doesn't seem nice, but can pass one pointer]
3. Pass to CCar(CCarManager *pCarManager, CTruckManager *pTruckManager....)
   [Hard to extend]
4. Use Observer pattern e.g. CCar.Attach(CCarManager), CCar.Attach(CTruckManager);
   [Easy to extend, but main focus become for  dealing method calls, what parts are responsible for what etc., also lot of check's]
5. Factory.

   class CCarFactory(CCarManager *pMngr)
   {
       CCar *CreateCar()
       {
           return CCar(m_pCarManager);
       }
   }

what are the other ways?

Comment: hmm I smell an [Anemic Domain Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) you might consider having the various entities enforce their own business logic. After that it's really a question of how do you do repositories for the entities.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference to `CResourceManager`, `CTruckManager`, etc. in `CCar`'s constructor.

```
CCar(const CResourceManager& resourceMgr, const CTruckManager& truckMgr):
    _resourceMgr(resourceMgr), _truckMgr(truckMgr) {
    //relevant construtor code here
}
```

This way it's easy to test with mock implementations as well. It's hard to say without knowing what the 'Manager classes do.

IMHO, classes whose names end in 'Manager' are often either poorly named (which I've done more times than I can count), or poorly designed.

Comment: Sounds sound ;o) ... He could additionally encapsulate construction of the dependent objects and their decorations within an 'externally' configurable Factory.

Comment: "IMHO, classes whose names end in 'Manager' are often either poorly named (which I've done more times than I can count), or poorly designed." I guess due to the lack of experience I have the same problem, could you share what you do?

Answer (score -1):

If the only reason you won't use the Singleton pattern is because you don't like it, I think you might want to reconsider your approach.

Singletons are a perfect pattern for what you're trying to acheive here. You have management classes that should only have *one instance* and require access from many other classes.

Comment: I starting agree with you about singletons. Thanks!

Comment: The singleton pattern is hardly ever the right choice. Object factories are the only one to even come to mind. They increase coupling, complicat testing, and are usually more trouble than they're worth.

Answer (score -1):

Its hard to say without some more specifications... If CCar requires special access to the manager methods (like internal variables/methods) or vice-versa, you can declare in CCar managers as friend, or CCar as friend in those manager classes.

simple example, mind the poor member names

```
class CCar
{
    int I;
public:
    friend class CManager;
    CCar(int i): I(i) {}

};

class CManager
{
    int D;
public:
    CManager(int i, CCar& car): D(i) 
    {
        car.I = 5;      // modify CCar instance internal member
    }

};
```

or vice versa if its the other way around.

If a CCar instance can have multiple CCarManagers, you could set up an array of pointers to 'link' those managers to an instance of CCar. Rather than having 3 different pManager arrays, having a Manager base class, and subclassing those managers to it, will let you store all references to managers in a single array.

```
class Manager // etc...

class CResourceManager : public Manager 

// in CCar
std::vector<Manager*> _mgrs;
// or if heap allocated
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Manager>> _mgrs; // assuming multiple CCars can reference same manager instance
```

Another method could be to have a struct/class that can hold all manager references for a particular instance.

```
struct MgrRefs
{
    std::vector<CCarManager*> _pCarMgrs;
    std::vector<CResourceManager*> _pResMgrs;
    // etc....
};
```

Comment: How to gain OO Design experience?, how to know what you are designing the good/right OO? I read about design patters, have used them, but still I feeling quite weak. The point is what usually the open source projects uses globals and other stuff, where many articles claim to avoid them.

Comment: Sometimes globals are better than the alternative, but that's hardly ever the case. The fact is that in the real world, be it open source projects or the enterprise, you'll find many example that contradict what the books say. It happens for many reasons, but more often than not because whoever wrote it just wanted to get their task done. To gain experience, write more code. The more you write, the more you'll make mistakes and learn not to make them again. "An expert is a person who's made every mistake possible".